# How to open CMD from PowerShell script in a new virtual desktop?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-10

how to open CMD from powershell script in a new virtual desktop?

I know how to open virtual desktop:

```bsh
$KeyShortcut = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
//WIN + CTRL + D: Create a new desktop
public static void CreateVirtualDesktopInWin10()
{
    //Key down
    keybd_event((byte)0x5B, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); //Left Windows key 
    keybd_event((byte)0x11, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); //CTRL
    keybd_event((byte)0x44, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero); //D
    //Key up
    keybd_event((byte)0x5B, 0, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
    keybd_event((byte)0x11, 0, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
    keybd_event((byte)0x44, 0, (uint)0x2, UIntPtr.Zero);
}
"@ -Name CreateVirtualDesktop -UsingNamespace System.Threading -PassThru
$KeyShortcut::CreateVirtualDesktopInWin10()
```

Then still in PowerShell script I open cmd and run some script

```bsh
CMD.EXE /C
cd "C:/users/.../..."
somescript
```

But CMD is opened in current desktop and not in new created virtual desktop.

Any advice? Need to open CMD in new virtual desktop and then call somescript.

Comment: You can't create windows directly in virtual desktops. You can [move them after they're created](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/mt186443), but because you don't know what desktop you've just created with your keystroke shenanigans, you can't do that either. It looks like MS deliberately limited the API surface to prevent applications from abusing their privileges, as they have done every time in the past with every shell interface ever created.

Comment: I can open new browser in new virtual desktop using arguments

Start-Process -FilePath Chrome -ArgumentList '--new-window http://localhost:3000/#/home'

Comment: So you can. What a weird and disconcerting loophole. So why didn't you try that with `cmd`, then? Because `Start-Process cmd` works fine on my machine.